# Sort a pie chart by slice size

Tags: highcharts

Currently I have a pie chart that contains a lot of data labels and information. I'm trying to make the most useful information easy to find, and that being said, I'm looking for a way to sort a pie chart by the slice size.

For example, if a pie chart was divided into fourths, each slice having 10%, 20%, 30%, and 40% respectively, how can I get the chart to sort in order ascending or descending? (Let's say it currently sorts the pie into 10%, 30%, 40%, 20%).

Any and all help would be great.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't sort your series data? Highcharts is just displaying it in the order you give it.

Comment: The data isn't being put in the standard way that highcharts API/examples show. The data property holds a `chartData` variable that is pulling the data from another server. Thus, I can't manually handle any of the data without using the variable `chartData`

Comment: Before chart initialise, why chartData variable cannot be used to prepare other order of data?